# Can't install @quasar/icongenie Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng is installed

Tags: quasar, libpng, pngquant

after upgrading Quasar and capacitor I'm not able to use or install icongenie anymore.
After that, I freshly installed my MacBook completely new with Sonoma 14.1, installed @quasar/cli 2.3.0 and then I tried to install @quasar/icongenie again but same Error:

```
error /Users/kai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pngquant-bin: Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command: node lib/install.js Arguments: Directory: /Users/kai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pngquant-bin Output: spawn Unknown system error -86 pngquant pre-build test failed compiling from source Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng is installed     at /Users/kai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)     at async Promise.all (index 0) info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this c
```

I already have a ready-to-publish App, I just wanted to upgrade everything, but my assets were deleted and icongenie is not installable anymore. HELP!

I tried:
yarn global add @quasar/icongenie
npm i -g @quasar/icongenie